# anjular promise not set a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wont handled promise in other function, but after worked first callback variable not change. Please help me. See my code here:

```
    this.handlerLocalDef = function(defer) {
        var hash = {};

        defer.then(
               function(response) {
                   hash = response;
               },

               function(err) {
                   showPopup(err);
               }
        );

        return hash;
    };



    var initialized = function()  {
        var localRegDef = Localization.getLocalizedDefer('regularform'),
            localPaymDef = Localization.getLocalizedDefer('payment');


            localizeRegForm = self.handlerLocalDef(localRegDef, localizeRegForm);

            $timeout(function() {
                console.log("localizeRegForm", localizeRegForm);
            },5000);
   }();
```

console log return me localizeRegForm: {}

Comment: So what happens if it takes longer than 5 seconds to process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `hash = response` you are only setting the local variable to reference another object. The receiver of the original returned object still keeps that object. A quick solution is to do `angular.extend(hash,response);`. This will copy all members of respose into the object referenced by `hash`, which is the original returned object. So the receiver will suddenly see those members.

**Caveat**: will neither work for values (strings, numbers, booleans, undefined, null) nor for arrays.

---

This is a fiddle with the above suggestion that works: http://jsfiddle.net/sVRCg/3/

---

However I get the feelig that the entire setup is wrong. How will you know that the `hash` is actually extended with `response`? Polling (e.g. `setTimeout`) is an awkward solution. I suggest you returned the promise instead; this way you can find out exactly when the response is available.

Another way is how `ngResource` does it; this is quite complicated, check out the code.

Comment: That's not correct. The receiver does not keep the "original" object. It holds a reference to the correct object, it's just that at the time the processing of that object occurs, it's probably still empty. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/sVRCg/1/

Comment: What I wrote is correct, perhaps you did not understand it. Take  a look at updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sVRCg/2/ and then to what I suggested and works: http://jsfiddle.net/sVRCg/3/

Comment: You're correct, I didn't pay attention to the fact that the OP was setting hash equal to response rather than just appending hash with response - using extend. Downvote removed.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you do async programming.

You do not set an arbitrary timeout and hope that you have data at that point, you must use the deferred object the way it was intended and use callbacks. This is one way of restructuring your code so that it will work. Depending on your specific circumstances, it may or may not serve your purpose:

```
    this.handlerLocalDef = function(defer,callback) {

        defer.then(
               function(response) {
                   callback.apply(this,[response])
               },

               function(err) {
                   showPopup(err);
               }
        );

    };



    var initialized = function()  {
        var localRegDef = Localization.getLocalizedDefer('regularform'),
            localPaymDef = Localization.getLocalizedDefer('payment');


            self.handlerLocalDef(localRegDef,function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
   }();
```